# Sub string from the String

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string "552 s hello"
I want to get the "552" in one substring and "s" in other substring and I want to split this String on the basis of first two spaces.Please help...

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: He managed to write the question out. Plus this is just a java question, no need for the android tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#split(String regex)`:

```
 String[] sp="552 s hello".split(" ");
 String fiveFiveTwo=sp[0];
 String letterS=sp[1];
```

The names aren't very useful in the end, so you'll want to rename the strings I've created. You should also catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: and how about hello how to get it? and i want to get all the string after "s" space.. ?

Comment: @Talib It's just an array...

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
String t = "522 s hello"
String[] test = t.split(" ");
```

Now in the String array you will have three values, "522", "s" and "hello. And you can now access each.